# Load Test using Java - timer task vs scheduler

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, concurrency, load-testing

I need to execute a load test using Java in which one of the test strategies require x threads to be fired of every y period of time for z minutes and thereafter have a constant totalThread amount of threads running for the load test duration (eg with a total of 100 threads, start 10 threads at 5 second intervals until all 100 threads have started, and continue to keep all 100 threading running (once it has finished execution it should restart) for the specified duration of the test, say one hour)

I have attempted to use the timer task but it seems limiting, would thread pool scheduler be a better option? What would be the best approach?

```
public class MyTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("STARTING THREAD "+ counter +" "+ new Date());
        //execute test
        counter++;

        if (counter > maxIterations) {
            MyTask.this.cancel();
            return;
        }
    }

    List<TimerTask> MyTaskList = new ArrayList<TimerTask>();   
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= threadsPerIteration ; i++) {
        TimerTask MyTimerTask = new MyTask(NumberOfIterations);
        MyTaskList.add(MyTimerTask);

        timer.schedule(MyTimerTask, initialDelayMilli, threadDelayMilli);
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: Is using a proper tool, such as [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) out of the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it is.

Comment: What about considering CLIFF load testing tool, which allows you to do this exact scheduling.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use any load testing tool, this has to be implemented directly into the scripts.

Comment: `TimerTask` uses a dedicated thread, so it can be expensive (creation, context switching) whereas a `ScheduledExecutorService` passes messages to a (potentially active) waiting thread. I think it would be more predictable. Ideally you might use [gattling](http://gatling.io), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, i decided to use the threadpool executor together with the timertask class as follows:

I used the Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(int x) method to control the amount of threads able to run concurrently, together with a timer task that is set to increase the threadpool size every y amount of time :

```
   TimerTask DelayTimerTask = new TimerTask() { //task to increase threadpool size

          public void run() {
            MyExecutor.setCorePoolSize(i * incrementAmount);          //timer task increments threadpool size by threadPoolIncrement
            i++;
        }
      };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(DelayTimerTask,0,intervalLength);
```

in this way the amount of concurrent threads will increase by incrementAmount every intervalLength.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a TimerTask for each thread.  Instead, use a single TimerTask, that fires once per interval, with your example numbers once every 5 seconds.

Each of the first 10 times the TimerTask fires, it spawns off 10 threads.  On each subsequent firing, it checks for the number of active threads, and spawns off enough new threads to bring the total to 100, until the end of your test.